# Staged Internal file csv.gz giving error that file does not match size of corresponding table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to copy a csv.gz file into a table I created to start analyzing location data for a map. I was running into an error that says that there are too many characters, and I should add a on_error option. However, I am not sure if that will help load the data, can you take a look?

Data source: https://data.world/cityofchicago/array-of-things-locations

```html
SELECT * FROM staged/array-of-things-locations-1.csv.gz


CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ARRAYLOC(name varchar, location_type varchar, category varchar, notes varchar, status1 varchar, latitude number, longitude number, location_2 variant, location variant);

COPY INTO ARRAYLOC
   FROM @staged/array-of-things-locations-1.csv.gz;
 
 CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT t_csv
   TYPE = "CSV"
   COMPRESSION = "GZIP"
   FILE_EXTENSION= 'csv.gz'
 
 CREAT OR REPLACE STAGE staged
    FILE_FORMAT='t_csv';
    
COPY INTO ARRAYLOC FROM @~/staged file_format = (format_name = 't_csv');
```

Error message:

```
Number of columns in file (8) does not match that of the corresponding table (9), use file format option error_on_column_count_mismatch=false to ignore this error File '@~/staged/array-of-things-locations-1.csv.gz', line 2, character 1 Row 1 starts at line 1, column "ARRAYLOC"["LOCATION_2":8] If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.
```

Solved: 
The real issue was that I need to better clean the data I was staging. This was my error.  This is what I ended up changing: the column types, changing the file from " to ' and had to separate one column due to  a comma in the middle of the data.

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ARRAYLOC(name varchar, location_type varchar, category varchar, notes varchar, status1 varchar, latitude float, longitude varchar, location varchar);

COPY INTO ARRAYLOC
   FROM @staged/array-of-things-locations-1.csv.gz;
 
 CREATE or Replace FILE FORMAT r_csv
   TYPE = "CSV"
   COMPRESSION = "GZIP"
   FILE_EXTENSION= 'csv.gz'
   SKIP_HEADER = 1
   ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH=FALSE
   EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = TRUE;
 
 create or replace stage staged
    file_format='r_csv';
    
copy into ARRAYLOC from @~/staged 
   file_format = (format_name = 'r_csv');
   
SELECT * FROM ARRAYLOC LIMIT 10;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error doesn't say that you have too many characters but that your file has 8 columns and your table has 9 columns, so it doesn't know how to align the columns from the file to the columns in the table.

You can list out the columns specifically using a subquery in your `COPY INTO` statement.

***Notes:***

- Columns from the file are positional based, so $1 is the first column in the file, $2 is the second, etc....
- You can put the columns from the file in any order that you need to match your table.
- You'll need to find the column that doesn't have data coming in from the file and either fill it with `null` or some default value.  In my example, I assume it is the last column and in it I will put the current timestamp.
- It helps to list out the columns of the table behind the table name, but this is not required.

***Example:***

```
COPY INTO ARRAYLOC (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4,COLUMN5,COLUMN6,COLUMN7,COLUMN8,COLUMN9)
FROM (
    SELECT $1
      ,$2 
      ,$3 
      ,$4 
      ,$5 
      ,$6 
      ,$7 
      ,$8
      ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
   FROM @staged/array-of-things-locations-1.csv.gz
);
```

I will advise against changing the `ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH` parameter, doing so could result in data ending up in the wrong column of the table.  I would also advise against changing the `ON_ERROR` parameter as I believe it is best to be alerted of such errors rather than suppressing them.

Comment: So this worked after I removed the Current_Timestamp(), but loaded no data. I had to update data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, setting that option should help. From [the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html):

> ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE | FALSE
>   Use: Data loading only
>
> Definition: Boolean that specifies whether to generate a parsing error
>   if the number of delimited columns (i.e. fields) in an input file does
>   not match the number of columns in the corresponding table.
>
> If set to FALSE, an error is not generated and the load continues. If
>   the file is successfully loaded:
>
> If the input file contains records with more fields than columns in
>   the table, the matching fields are loaded in order of occurrence in
>   the file and the remaining fields are not loaded.
>
> If the input file contains records with fewer fields than columns in
>   the table, the non-matching columns in the table are loaded with NULL
>   values.
>
> This option assumes all the records within the input file are the same
>   length (i.e. a file containing records of varying length return an
>   error regardless of the value specified for this parameter).

So assuming you are okay with getting `NULL` values for the missing column in your input data, you can use `ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH=FALSE` to load the file successfully.

Comment: This helped with the mismatch, but in truth I ended up cleaning up the data.

Answer (score 0):

When viewing that table directly on data.world, there are columns named both **location** and **location_2** with identical data.  It looks like that display is erroneous, because when downloading the CSV, it has only a single **location** column.

I suspect if you change your `CREATE OR REPLACE` statement with the following statement that omits the creation of **location_2**, you'll get to where you want to go:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ARRAYLOC(name varchar, location_type varchar, category varchar, notes varchar, status1 varchar, latitude number, longitude number, location variant);
```

Comment: This was the first error, that fixed it, however I was also missing a lot more cleaning of the data. So I just removed the file from stage and started over.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got the same error but changed my field_delimiter from "|" to ","

```
create or replace file format 
file_formats.csv_format
type = csv 
field_delimiter = ','
skip_header = 1 
empty_field_as_null = True;
```