# bulk load into snowflake breaks when field has a double-quote in it

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, bulk-load

I am loading data from file in S3 using copy into command and have following parameters:

```
file_format = (
 type = 'csv'
 field_delimiter = '~'
 FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY= '"'
 EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = TRUE
 NULL_IF=""
 ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = None)
```

My load is breaking every time I have double-quote inside a field.  I tried to replace it by escape \" and adding escape = '\' to the file format parameters, but nothing seems to work.
Can someone offer a solution?

Thank you,

Comment: Did you try `ESCAPE='\\'` ?  (With double slashes.)

Comment: If your fields have double quotes, you will need to escape them with another set of double quotes.  For example, if your field looks like "John replied "Yes" to our survey", the data will need to be escaped like this:  "John replied ""Yes"" to our survey".   This is usually the most straightforward solution.

Comment: If you have a double or single quote within the text field, you can not use FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY= '"' , it has to be set as None and once it is loaded into staged table, you need to either apply replace or any UDF to load to final table.

Comment: I tried using ESCAPE='\\' - didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
Create or replace file format name
 file_format = (type = 'csv')
 field_delimiter = '~' 
 FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY= '"' 
 EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = TRUE 
 NULL_IF="" 
 ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\\'
```

Can you please share a data sample? Is the staged file on S3 compressed?

COMPRESSION = AUTO

Comment: This is a sample record which had " inside a field

Comment: 25966687~587869~445588-1017084-STD-AAAA~4488~1017084-STD-AAAA ~227306466~4488-6ea17312dc3b2b3b4488~Y~"21  Replacement Boot Laces"~"Allen Edmonds 21  Replacement Boot Laces"~"https://www.xxxxxxx.com/xxxxx-care/mens-shoe-care/laces/21-replacement-boot-laces/1017084dd-AAAA-STD.html"~"Allen Edmonds"~5~USD~~~US~MERCHANT~2020-01-12~Y~~N~N~"1017084 21" Brown  (2-3 eyelets)"~~"new"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~2019-09-20~2020-01-12~~~~~~~~~2020-01-13~165783~~N~0~"SF1017084"~"21  Replacement Boot Laces"

Comment: I see it this data "1017084 21" Brown (2-3 eyelets)", there was a similar question that you can select the variant table with $1, this pattern and so on. This was the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59687926/staged-internal-file-csv-gz-giving-error-that-file-does-not-match-size-of-corres

Comment: i don't want to do select from files, I would prefer to load by using copy into .. command which can load the whole directory of files.  I have 250mln records which partitioned in many files..

Comment: There are two more opportunities that were researched. In order for the answer provided to work you would need to add an escape character in front of each instance where there was a " in the middle of a data set. ("1017084 21\" Brown (2-3 eyelets)") Second, the ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD =  defaults to \\ as for the " in the col - so you could also edit all of the " to be """ and set FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY =” ” ”